# 5.5 version works where as 5.6 doesn't work

Tags: soapui

There is a web-service URL which required user id and password. And wsdl file exist for the same.

The request has been sent as XML with credentials via SOAP UI. It works fine with 5.5 version.

When the same has been tested in 5.6 version it throws error the reason is password is being displayed as null.

Is it a bug in 5.6 version ? Does anyone come across this issue in 5.6 ?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like your have different versions on dev vs production? Or are you trying to upgrade to a new version? Also *"Is it a bug in 5.6 version ? Does anyone come across this issue in 5.6 ?"* Without the code and or the WSDL we know even less then you.

Comment: does WSDL version matters with SOAP UI ? SOAP UI is just a client correct. Any major upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6

Comment: *"does WSDL version matters with SOAP UI"* SOAP and WSDL are declaratieve XML languages, without WSDL we don't know annything..

Comment: Soap 5.5 maximum version of WSDL supported? Do you know any link where i can check the compatability ?

Comment: The WSDL is used by SoapUI to only build your project, specifically all the endpoint methods and parameters. Once you run your tests, the WSDL is no longer used. Your problem is elsewhere. However, with the amount of information you provided, this could be a very long guessing game. Please have a read through [ask] and [mcve].